# How to get rid of "Permission denied" error in TeamCity

Tags: docker, teamcity, eslint

I have react app with `lint` script in `package.json` file:

```
{
   ...,
   scripts: {
    "lint": "eslint src/"
   }
}
```

I have added build to TeamCity which will run this script with options:

```
Runner type: Command Line,
Run: Custom Script, 
Custom script:
   rm -rf node_modules
   npm install
   npm run lint
Run step within Docker container: node:latest
Docker image platform: Linux
```

But I get error `sh: 1: eslint: Permission denied` when this step runs. I have tried adding access with `chmod` to node_modules, but there was no luck. I've googled a lot but could not figure out solution.

UPD 
Full log in TeamCity:

```
[11:12:13][Step 2/2] 
[11:12:13][Step 2/2] > @siren/app@1.0.0 lint /opt/buildagent/work/d517340ad681961
[11:12:13][Step 2/2] > eslint src/
[11:12:13][Step 2/2] 
[11:12:13][Step 2/2] sh: 1: eslint: Permission denied
[11:12:13][Step 2/2] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[11:12:13][Step 2/2] npm ERR! errno 126
[11:12:13][Step 2/2] npm ERR! @siren/app@1.0.0 lint: `eslint src/`
[11:12:13][Step 2/2] npm ERR! Exit status 126
[11:12:13][Step 2/2] npm ERR! 
[11:12:13][Step 2/2] npm ERR! Failed at the @siren/app@1.0.0 lint script.
[11:12:13][Step 2/2] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[11:12:13][Step 2/2] 
[11:12:13][Step 2/2] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[11:12:13][Step 2/2] npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-12-23T08_12_13_723Z-debug.log
[11:12:14][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 126
[11:12:14][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 126 (Step: Lint CI (Command Line))
[11:12:14][Step 2/2] Step Lint CI (Command Line) failed
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: share the dockerfile and full command line logs.

Comment: Added log in question. I have no docker file for build step in Teamcity. TeamCity just provides some options which I can edit:
`Run step within Docker container`,
`Docker image platform`,
`Pull image explicitly`,
`Additional docker run arguments`

Comment: I think if there would be such option as "Run as root user" it would have solved problem, but there is no such

Comment: Is lint installed globally on the build agent or through the package.json? I suspect the former and that it was installed as sudo, but now the agent is running under another account. Perhaps log into the agent as the same user that the agent uses and `npm install lint` with that user.

Comment: Script is running in docker container and not the agent itself, nothing is installed globally, everything comes from `package.json`. I don't know under which user teamcity logges into docker container (container is created by teamcity)